# What are the best practices for handle read/writes user data in SQLite?

Tags: java, sqlite

I am a developer for a server in Minecraft, we recently opened and experienced server crashes (host issue), those crashes enabled loss of data (in our main plugin) from a lot of players because it would save only when they log off. I have thought of a solution but when more than 2 messages are written in chat it throws an SQL exception saying the database is closed. We are using SQLite.

**Old Logging off saving method.**

what I would do for each player on login is to select all the columns from "Players" table and put all the information in a HashMap, as the server ran I would get/put data into the HashMap and when a player logs off/the server closes it would take the HashMap and place it back into our SQLite file.

code from SQLite to HashMap

```
private void playerRecordToMap() throws SQLException
{
    List<String> columnNames = getDB().queryColumnName(Statements.SELECT("Players", pUUID));

    for (String column : columnNames)
    {
        if (!column.equals("UUID"))
        {
            System.out.println(column);
            Object obj = getDB().queryValue(Statements.SELECT_COLUMN("Players", column, pUUID), column);
            if (obj != null)
            {
                playerRecord.put(column, obj);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

HashMap to SQLite

```
public void mapToPlayerRecord()
{
    for (String s : playerRecord.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println(s);
        getDB().executeStatement(Statements.UPDATE("Players", s, playerRecord.get(s).toString(), pUUID));
    }
}
```

e.g. getting a value using the old way.

```
public Rank getRank()
{
    int rankId = (int) playerRecord.get("RANK");
    return Rank.fromId(rankId);
}
```

Since the server crashed multiple times and it could potentially happen in the future, I realized that in order to prevent data loss I should communicate with the SQLite file directly but that of course lead to an SQLException that the database is closed.

**New saving method**

```
public Rank getRank()
{
    String GET_RANK = Statements.SELECT("Players", pUUID);
    int rankId = (int) getDB().queryValue(GET_RANK, "RANK");
    return Rank.fromId(rankId);
}

public void setRank(int id)
{
    String UPDATE_RANK = Statements.UPDATE("Players", "RANK", String.valueOf(id), pUUID);
    getDB().executeStatement(UPDATE_RANK);
}
```

I have checked all the statement methods in my "Statements" class and they have no issues since they worked with the old way.

As soon as a player writes more than one message in chat it throws that exception (since every chat message it requires the player's rank & some other info which the plugin pulls straight from the SQLite file).

**query value & execute statement methods**

```
public Boolean executeStatement(String statement)
{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try
    {
        conn = getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(statement);
        return !ps.execute();
    } catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "can't execute", ex);
        return false;
    } finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (ps != null)
                ps.close();
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "can't close connection", ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public Object queryValue(String statement, String row)
{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        conn = getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(statement);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next())
        {
            return rs.getObject(row);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "can't execute", ex);
    } finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (ps != null)
                ps.close();
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "can't close connection", ex);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**My question is:
What's the best way to handle that situation I described above and how do I do it?**

Edit:
Weirdly enough I have done multiple testing on my test server and it crashes with a very similar maybe even the same error that my host shows, yet it doesn't look like a plugin error.

[error log in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/77tLmUQs)

Edit 2:
The error in edit 1 seems to be caused by SQLite, so that leads us back to the what is the solution of the question...